# Visual Studio Designer not showing controls for UWP Apps

Tags: uwp, designer

XAML Designer is not displaying controls in a way they are visble. The controls are there, if you click where one should be the outline borders are highlighted and the proper xaml code is selected. With nothing selected it looks like a blank pallet with just the page outlined. I have tried the blue, blue extra contrast, dark and light color theme. Same issue all themes. I have also tried switching between ARM, x86 and x64 with issue in all three. There are no messages in the Error List. Have opened multiple solutions same result.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: i am unable to understand what you want , i tested your code output is correct according to your codes here is screenshot of my output https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ahppl6XCmlXfk-txMR7sNERAlm7nsw
Try to debug your code also

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is, that the designer window does not show the elements from the code (for example the TextBlock). This is the same vor every element i paste from the toolbox into the designer window. In your screenshot everything is ok.I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Can you debug your project may be result will same. Or try to restart your visual studio , still if you have problem you can use relative pannel for better alignment of controls, relative pannel is really great control for getting things in place according to screen type. And also check your cpu and ram usage may be high usage of cpu protecting updating of designer windows in visual studio. Debug first and reply me how your output looks . Or alternately your are in starting of project you can create new project and delete it

Comment: Ok you are right, now it works. Sorry, it's my first day with Visual Studio.Thank you very much!

Comment: Ha ha okay , ask again if you have any problem related to programming. Check your system configuration also, in my case i am using old core 2 duo 2.9ghz without hyper threading support but works very fine because of motherboard config, so choice your system by looking to every component

Comment: @ShubhamSahu You could make your comments as an answer for this question.

Comment: Okay ;) @XavierXie-MSFT

Answer (score 1):

As i build your code which gives correct output

**Your Codes**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Ellipse Name="LED" Fill="LightGray" Stroke="White" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="10" />
        <TextBlock Name="DelayText" Text="500ms" Margin="10" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="26.667"/>
        <TextBlock Name="GpioStatus" Text="Waiting To Initialize GPIO..." Margin="10,50,10,10" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="26.667" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

**Suggestion**

For Better Alignment Of Elements You Can Use **RelativePanel** which allow Developer to better arrangement of elements in UWP apps

Further the problem you face in visual studio Designer is Related to your CPU performance which protect designer to update in real time, you can try Debug your app which may give correct result.
And find processes in task manager any process other than visual studio and its components may consume your CPU and RAM-

[image: Usage Monitor In Task Manager]

And View Your System Configuration which should be enough but you don't need very high configuration PC for app development it should minimal which can easily handle all visual studio process , if you planning to game development then you need a higher one according to your game development.