# UWP Design Unresponsive after Run

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I seem to have an issue on multiple machines running VS2017, specifically in UWP projects. After the project is run, the Design views become unresponsive and need to be closed and reopened... Has anyone come across this or know of any fixes? Its not a dealbreaker but its slows down the workflow :D

Thanks!

Comment: when you run vs2017 goto task manager and monitor your ram and cpu usage or follow my this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46254312/visual-studio-designer-not-showing-controls-for-uwp-apps/46292910#46292910

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of possible reasons for a designer issue. So we need to check for details when it is possible.
Visual Studio supports a way to troubleshoot designer issue, you can see this blog:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/02/24/troubleshooting-extensions-with-the-activity-log/

It's old but the command still works for VS2017. You can type the "devenv /log" command from Developer Command for Visual Studio 2017, then try reproduce your problem and check the generated log after that. You can also report it directly from Visual Studio->Help->Report a problem.